How can I load values from a csv file to a dropdown list without uploading?
I want to load values from a csv file to a dropdown list using Javascript. But I cannot do it without uploading first. On document ready function, I want the values to show on my dropdown list.
I know how to get the values using FileReader() but I don't want that. Is it possible by just referencing it to a .csv file?

You can't read from a local file directly in JavaScript, it would open a huge security hole. You have to use the FileReader API.

Is it possible to use FileReader() without uploading?

Of course it is. It can only be used to read local files, but the user has to select it from a dialogue.

Let's be sure we're using the same terminology. Uploading is sending a file from your PC to the server, downloading is getting the file from the server to your PC.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

I think what I want to happen is not possible due to security reasons. Thank you for your help

Use the fetch api. You'll have to host the csv on a server and call it with a GET request.
You used to be able to retrieve local files using fetch but it's no longer supported in Chrome and Firefox for security purposes.

I see. I used Chrome and been having a hard time. I'll try to upload the csv on a server then use fetch. Thank you.

Fetch is for reading remote files, which is why you have to upload first.

I see. I think what I want to happen is not possible due to security reasons. Thank you for your help
